# Issue resolving Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sum, coalesce

```
SELECT tic.DATE AS submit_date
    ,sum(tic.issues_created) AS issues_created
    ,COALESCE(sum(y.issues_closed), 0) AS issues_closed
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN tic.action = 1
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS issues_routed
    ,COALESCE(y.issue_r_acc, 0) AS issue_r_acc
    ,COALESCE(y.accuracy, 0) AS issue_r_acccy
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN tic.action = 2
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS issue_rec
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN tic.action = 3
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS issue_ig
FROM (
    SELECT d.DATE
        ,count(x.incident_id) AS issues_created
        ,x.action
    FROM (
        SELECT to_char(date_trunc('day', ((CURRENT_DATE - 1) - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATE
        FROM generate_series(0, 6, 1) AS offs
        ) d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM incident
        WHERE id = 100
        ) x ON (d.DATE = to_char(date_trunc('day', x.submit_date), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    GROUP BY d.DATE
        ,x.submit_date
        ,x.action
    ORDER BY d.DATE DESC
    ) AS tic
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT submit_date
        ,number_of_match_incidents AS issue_r_acc
        ,number_of_incidents AS issues_closed
        ,number_of_match_incidents / number_of_incidents AS accuracy
    FROM pred
    WHERE id = 100
        AND type = 1
        AND label = 'ABC'
    ) y ON (tic.DATE = to_char(date_trunc('day', y.submit_date), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
GROUP BY tic.DATE
    ,tic.issues_created
    ,COALESCE(y.issue_r_acc, 0)
    ,COALESCE(y.issues_closed, 0)
    ,COALESCE(y.accuracy, 0)
ORDER BY tic.DATE DESC
```

I need to get sum of all incidents sum(tic.issues_created) from the incident table along with other columns over a period of 7 days.

But I am facing issues as I have to order it by action and hence it gives the total incident count as incorrect.

What am I missing?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: `to_char(date_trunc('day', ((CURRENT_DATE - 1) - offs)), ...` You don't need to cast to character.